# True Path to Resource folder and images/files in project?

Tags: c#, resources

Example to tray icons:

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Properties.Resources.Icon1);
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
notifyIcon1.Text = "Tray Icon TestTXT";
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Properties.Resources not contain Icon1

But the file already exists in the Project folder.

Does anyone know how to write the file path to Properties.Resources and other project files?

Or - how to correctly add the file so I can access it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the solution in the "solution explorer" and click on "Add" then "Add existing item" Browse to the file you are looking for and press Ok

You might have to change the file type to "All files" when you are looking for the file